# Questions on SXSSFWorkbook about it's FlushedRows, Written to Disk and rowAccessWindowSize

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need to write a millions of record in an Excel(.xlsx) file on an already existing template(.xlsx). Initially I was using XSSFWorkbook and that obviously leads me to OOM issue.

Then later, I have changed to SXSSFWorkbook to avoid the OOM issue like below,

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(fis);
XSSFWorkbook mainBook = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(mainBook,200);
Sheet sh = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
Row row0 = sh.createRow(0);
```

In SXSSFWorkbook, we can't modify the existing template and so I kept the template empty to write the data with column headers as well.

But on `row0 = sh.createRow(0);`, It is throwing error like "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempting to write a `row[0]` in the range `[0,106403]` that is already written to disk"

I am not at all sure like, How "106403" written to disk and what should i do further ?

So arises the doubt on these three,

1. What is FlushedRows and how it is flushing the rows 106403 while I am trying to create a new row?
2. What is "Written to Disk"?
3. While Initializing "SXSSFWorkbook" with parameter "rowAccessWindowSize", in my case it is 200 and what is rowAccessWindowSize and what it will do?

Comment: "I kept the template empty": This is not true. The error message: `Attempting to write a row[0] in the range [0,106403] that is already written to disk` means there are 106403 rows already in `Sheet1` when `SXSSFWorkbook` was created via `SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(mainBook, 200);`. So at least there must be data in row 106404 of  `Sheet1`. For  your other questions pleas eread [SXSSFWorkbook API docu](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFWorkbook.html#SXSSFWorkbook-org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook-int-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SXSSFWorkbook](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFWorkbook.html) is for writing only. When a template `XSSFWorkbook` is used, then while creating `SXSSFWorkbook` from that `XSSFWorkbook` a temporary file is created for each sheet in that `XSSFWorkbook` and all existing rows in those sheets are written into those temporary files. Later on only new rows can be streamed into those temporary files.

The `rowAccessWindowSize` sets the count of rows  that kept in memory before they will flushed into the  temporary files. All rows that are written already to the temporary sheet file cannot be accessed anymore later because they are not more in memory but only in the temporary file. That's why the low memory usage of `SXSSF`.

The error message `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempting to write a row[0] in the range [0,106403] that is already written to disk.` tells you that the rows with indexes 0 to 106403 (rows 1 to 106404) are already written to disk. That tells you that your template sheet `Sheet1` is not empty. At least in row 106404 must be data. That's why the rows 1 to 106404 were written to `Sheet1`' s temporary file while `SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(mainBook,200);`. Later on only rows greater than row number 106405 can be created new on `SXSSFSheet`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info. Actual problem was in the for loop and so it was trying to write to an already written row.